# Como cambiar esta consulta sql a formato eloquent de laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Tengo esta consulta sql en laravel, pero quiero cambiarla a formato eloquent

```
$producto =DB::select('SELECT count(*) contador, p.nombre
FROM  detalle_boletas d 
inner join boletas b on  d.boleta_id = b.id
inner join productos p on d.producto_id = p.id
Where b.fecha = ("0000-00-00") 
GROUP BY p.nombre
HAVING COUNT(*)
order by contador desc
limit 5');
```

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega que has intentado

Answer (score 2):

Tu consulta quedaria así

```
  DetallesBolea::join('boletas','detalle_boletas.boleta_id','=','bolestas.id')
        ->join('productos', 'detalle_boletas.producto_id', '=', 'productos.id')
        ->where('boletas.fecha',"0000-00-00")
        ->select('productos.nombre',DB::raw('COUNT(boletas.id) as contador'))
        ->group_by('productos.nombre')
        ->order_by('contador', 'desc')
        ->limit(5)->get();
```

Comment: Tu consulta esta incompleta, al final debes encadenar el método `get()`

Comment: es correcto,gracias